# create auth permission dialog in facebook

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, permissions, authorization

basically i have integrated fb in my app and for that i have created the app in fb developer site.

I have got app id and i have authorized my app with fb using this id.

While asking permissions in fb, the auth dialog havn't appeared good. like i want to display auth dialog as below image.

[image]

but i didn't see above style of auth dialog while authorization. How will i get that style of dialog?.

Currently i am getting the below style of dialog.

[image]

Please advise in this regards.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your facebook profile from which you have created your app,or from which you are accessing your app.
Then go to **Privacy Setting -> Apps, Games and Websites**  
And here go to apps you use there click edit in front of your app and then remove it.
It will simply remove your permission and will ask you again as you have shown in screen.
If anything feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks!!!.. but what i meant is, my dialog not having that style like two buttons, logout link and layouts, etc.. So is there anything i have to set in app settings?..

Comment: by default buttons look like that first screenshot.Try to change browser , else add your screenshot.How you are viewing those buttons.